# get next element in foreach loop jsp/jstl

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl, jsp-tags

I have code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>JSTL forEach varStatus index Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <c:forEach items="${productList}" var="product" varStatus="status">
     <c:out value="${status.index+1}"/>.<c:out value="${product.name}" escapeXml="false" />
  </c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

which gives me the index and product.name from each iteration. For example,

```
1 product1
2 product2
3 product3
```

Now I cant find the answer anywhere is it possible to get the product.name from the NEXT iteration like i did with the `index` adding +1 to it. Could anyone please answer that question for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
  ${productList[status.index+1].name}
```